# How to return data in Promise Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a simple Promise like:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve();
    });
```

Also there is an object: `var obj = {};`

How to return this object in Promise described above?

Like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
          resolve(obj);
        });
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you have right now?

Comment: What you have is the right way to do it... please search before asking the question as this has already been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code snippet.

```
obj = {
  "fname": "data"
};

function getData() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(obj);
  });
}

getData().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oqsxcvn5/)**